# Easiest method for mapping polygons in GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, geojson, geodjango

I have a simple application with a PosGIS back end. I want to have a page per feature in the database. I have used a slug and a URL routing.

The PostGIS features have a polygon stored in a geom column which is modelled as a MultiPolygonField using geodjango.

What is the easiest way to parse this geom column in to geojson so that I can add it to a leaflet map?

Below is my code which is attempting to use the geojson serializer though I receive this error code on my page.

[image: Error Message]
Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Countries_App.models import Countries
from django.core.serializers import serialize
# Create your views here.

def show_country(request, country_slug):
# Create a context dictionary which we can pass
# to the template rendering engine.
context_dict = {}
try:
# Can we find a category name slug with the given name?
# If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
# So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
        country = Countries.objects.get(slug=country_slug)
        Country_geojson = serialize('geojson', 
Countries.objects.get(slug=country_slug))
# We also add the category object from
# the database to the context dictionary.
# We'll use this in the template to verify that the category exists.
        context_dict['Countries'] = country
except KeyError:
    country = []
    context_dict['Countries'] = Countries
    country_slug = none
    Country_geojson = serialize('geojson', 
Country.objects.filter(name=country_slug))
# Go render the response and return it to the client.
return render(request, 'Countries_App/country.html', {'context_dict': 
context_dict, 'Country_geojson': Country_geojson})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
# url(r'^country/(?P<country_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 
GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=Countries), name='data'),
url(r'^country/(?P<country_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.show_country, 
name='show_country'),
]
```

Excerpt from template where I attempt to add geojson to leaflet map

```
        var geojsonfeature = '{{ Countries_geojson }}'
    L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);
```

Am I approaching this in the right way? What is the easiest way to simply add a PostGIS polygon geometry to a template? Bearing in mind I only want to add the geometry of the feature that matches the slug.

Comment: Hey @Jamie2483 I was wondering, did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [django-geojson's documentation](https://django-geojson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#geojson-template-filter) there is the reference on how to use the module's tags into django templates:

> Mainly useful to dump features in HTML output and bypass AJAX call :
>
> ```
> // Leaflet JS L.geoJson({{
> object_list|geojsonfeature|safe}}).addTo(map);
> ```
>
> Will work either for a model, a geometry field or a queryset.
>
> ```
> {% load geojson_tags %}
>
> var feature = {{ object|geojsonfeature|safe }};
>
> var geom = {{ object.geom|geojsonfeature|safe }};
>
> var collection = {{ object_list|geojsonfeature|safe }};
> ```
>
> Properties and custom geometry field name can be provided.
>
> ```
> {{ object|geojsonfeature:"name,age" }}
> {{ object|geojsonfeature:"name,age:the_geom" }}
> {{ object|geojsonfeature:":geofield" }}
> ```